# TFS Build Error: File does not exist in source directory. (type InvalidOperationException)

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Can some one please shed some light on my problem.

My TFS Build is actually working.. by working i mean as far as it builds the solution and deploys the project via a publish profile.

However it always says my build has failed, under the heading "**Other Errors and Warnings**" there is this following error.

```
Exception Message: File does not exist in source directory. (type InvalidOperationException) 
Exception Stack Trace: 
    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
    at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Its not the most helpful error, how can i see what file its talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Queue build dialog sett the logging level to diagnostic.  Then run the build and examine the build log.

Comment: Turns out it was fruity build template, i went back to the default template it everything works fine.. :)